# How to pass the argument in pthread_create to function?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

The point is use multithread to find the prime numbers, In this case I use 2 of thread the first one is find a prime in range of (0,1000) and the second thread in range of (1000,2000)
But the program is can't run as I wish, I think the argument in pthread_create to the function is a problem

```
void *findprime(void *args){

    int i,j,temp=0;
    int count = 0;
    int n = *((int*)args);
    if (n==1000) {temp = 1;}
    if (n==2000) {temp = 1000;}

    for (i = temp; i <= n; i++)
    {
        count = 0;

        for (j = temp; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count == 2)
        {
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main () {
    pthread_t t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4, t_5;

    int t_1args = 1000;
    int t_2args = 2000;

    printf("Before Using Thread \n");

    pthread_create(&t_1, NULL , findprime, (void *)&t_1args);
    pthread_create(&t_2, NULL , findprime, (void *)&t_2args);

    pthread_join(t_1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t_2, NULL);

    printf("After Thread \n");

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the argument is a problem?

Comment: Hust as a side not: This is a Linux based solution using C. Are you allowed to use C++? Then life would be immediately simpler . . .

Comment: I think `for (i = temp; i <= n; i++)` should be `for (i = temp; i < n; i++)` https://ideone.com/hmcphf

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the arguments, they seem to be fine. The problem is with the loop counting the dividers:

```
        for (j = temp; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
```

In the second thread, what temp is initialized to?